# Redirect URL with /?1

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect an URL with `/?1` in the end, like

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/page/?1
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/other/path/to/page/
```

And I just can't find the solution. Important is to remove the `?1`. I don't know why there is this `?1` in the end and what exactly it is used for but I can't change it.

Here is what I tried (and didn't work):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} path/to/page/\?1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^other/path/to/page/ [NE]
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/page/?$ /other/path/to/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe reason why your attempt fails is that the "1" is *not* part of the URL, but of the query string. So this will probably work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^1$
RewriteRule ^/?path/to/page/?$ /path/to/page/ [END,QSD]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately there is an error in the http server error log file: `Invalid command 'RequestRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer:`

Comment: I changed `RequestRule` to `RewriteRule` and used the absolute path like `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^1$
RewriteRule ^/?path/to/page/?$ https://www.example.com/path/to/page/ [END,QSD]` And now it works!

Comment: Sorry, that was an obvious mistake I made, certainly it has to be `RewriteRule`! I changed the answer accordingly. About the rule target: an absolute path (`/path/to/page`) should definitely work, I see no reason why you'd have to use an _external_ redirection (which is _much_ more expensive, btw) for this.